# Accessing phone numbers from Contacts framework in iOS 9

Tags: swift, ios9

I'm having trouble unwrapping a `CNLabeledValue` to get the phone number. Here's my code (Swift), and what I'm currently getting is `<CNPhoneNumber: 0x12cefa000: countryCode=us, digits=4157119521>`. I just need to access the `digits` value, so I'm trying to print it within `for number in result.phoneNumbers {}`.

```
lazy var contacts: [CNContact] = {
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        let keysToFetch = [
            CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName),
            CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

        // Get all the containers
        var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
        do {
            allContainers = try contactStore.containersMatchingPredicate(nil)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching containers")
        }

        var results: [CNContact] = []

        // Iterate all containers and append their contacts to our results array
        for container in allContainers {
            let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier(container.identifier)

            do {
                let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
                for result in containerResults {

                    for number in result.phoneNumbers {

                        // WHAT SHOULD I PRINT HERE?????
                        print(number.value) 
                    }

                }
                results.appendContentsOf(containerResults)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching results for container")
            }
        }

        return results
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `stringValue` of `CNPhoneNumber` is formatted digits. You just need to some more further string decoration once you don't want to have symbols like, "-", "(" or ")".

```
for number in result.phoneNumbers {
    guard let numberValue = number.value as? CNPhoneNumber else {
        continue
    }
    print(numberValue)
    print(String(numberValue.stringValue.characters.filter({ !["-", "(", ")"].contains($0) })))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey) {
                for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
                    let label = CNLabeledValue.localizedStringForLabel(phoneNumber.label)

                    let phone = phoneNumber.value as! CNPhoneNumber
                        print(" \(label) \(phone.stringValue)")
                }
            }
```

this should print(i.e. default contact Anna Haro) :  home 555-522-8243

then you can format the "stringValue" the way you want